# modalpopup extender with iframe is not working

Tags: asp.net, iframe, modalpopupextender

I am using Modal popup for displaying different page in a popup and parent page is not editable

here is my code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnModalPopup" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnModalPopup_ModalPopupExtender" BehaviorID="btnModalPopup_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="ModalPopup" 
   BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnModalPopup"> </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
 <div id="ModalPopup" runat="server">
 <iframe id="iframePopup" runat="server" width="700" scrolling="yes" height="500"></iframe>
</div>
```

and code behind

```
iframePopup.Attributes.Add("src", "default.aspx");
btnModalPopup_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
```

But the iframe is showing in the main page not a popup please any body can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Button `Visible="true"` & use `style="display:none;"`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnModalPopup" runat="server" style="display:none;" 
Text="" Visible="true" />
```

Visible="true" ensures the control is rendered.

And, by setting `style="display:none;"` you can hide the control.